# How to do a FullText Search on Sql Server Table which includes special characters?

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to do a fulltext search on a table where one of the rows is a log and contains characters such as ,.: and so on. Currently when a query is ran using the 'Contains' keyword which includes any of those characters no rows are returned. Is there any advice on the best route that can be take for this search?
Here is what my current query look like at the moment:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[searchLog]
    @searchValue varchar(150)
    AS
    Declare @myquote varchar(10)
    Declare @wildcard varchar(5)
    set @myquote ='"'
    set @wildcard ='*'
    set @searchValue = @myquote + @searchValue + @wildcard +@myquote    
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT  o.ID, o.Name, o.DateRan, s.Name AS Job, o.Start, o.[End], o.Status, o.Logs
    FROM    dbo.o AS o LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.j AS j ON o.Job = j.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.s AS s ON j.Script = s.ID
WHERE CONTAINS ((o.Name, o.Logs),  @searchValue)  
ORDER BY o.ID DESC
```

Example of Logs being searched:

"Sunday, July 7, 2019 1:20:00 PM
 Seeking c:\xxxx\xxxx\log1_date.txt 
 Seeking c:\xxxx\xxxx\log2_date.txt
 Seeking c:\xxxx\xxxx\log4_date.txt
 Monday, July 8, 2019 1:20:00 PM   FTP AND PGP COMPLETED Processed 0 files ."

Comment: Can you show us an example log and example test search that does not give the desired result?

Comment: Generally, those are removed as noise words, have you edited your noise words list to include them?

Comment: @SeanGallardy I just updated the question with a sample. ill have to read up on editing noise words, but no i havent.

Comment: @tttony I updated the question.

Comment: @SeanGallardy there is no noise word lists that were created.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the CONTAINS function

```
SELECT * FROM [TableName] WHERE CONTAINS (*, 'Word')
```

Comment: That is what I am using currently.

Comment: And if you use the PATINDEX 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017